# As3/Flash: how to get object from the designer stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, stage

I am having problems getting items that i placed in my designer.
I work with external classes i link to my objects i place in my designer on the timeline.
I always assumed they where placed in the "stage" attribute in the as3 class.

However when i do:

```
trace(stage.getChildByName("thing"));
```

the item that i called thing in my designer is not found.
It actually returns null.

Does anyone know what attribute i need to target to get the items i already placed on my stage.
It would make everything a lot easier then dynamicly adding all the items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves, the objects place on the stage in the editor are a child of `root`, not `stage`.

If your code is on the timeline or the document class, the following should work.

```
this.getChildByName("thing");
```

If you are trying to access it from another object, the following should work.

```
(root as DisplayObjectContainer).getChildByName("thing");
```

Comment: thank you alot this awnsered my question, i tried looking at root. i knew it existed but because it did not had the getChildByName property i stopped looking at it. It is pretty stupid that you have to cast it as an DisplayObjectContainer to make it work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**My object's parent**

For an instance named `s` and placed on your `Stage`, or called by the code like in the following example, you just have to trace it's `parent` to know what you should write before your dot. Your object's parent is before your dot:

```
var s:Square = new Square();
addChild(s);
trace(s.parent); // [object MainTimeline]
trace(s.parent.parent); // [object Stage]
```

It means that your object is placed on your `MainTimeline`, which is itself placed on it's `Stage`.

To refer to the `Stage` object of a `DisplayObject`, you just have to use it's `stage` property:

```
trace('s Stage   ' + s.stage); // s Stage   [object Stage]
trace('this Stage   ' + this.stage); // this Stage   [object Stage]
```

By using the keyword `this`, you refer to your MainTimeline:

```
trace(this is MainTimeline); // true
```

Then to call your object you can write:

```
trace(s); // [object Square]
// or
trace(this.s); // [object Square]
```

**Should I use getChildByName method?**

You don't need to use `getChildByName` method to call an object. You can directly call it by it's name. Why using a method when it's not necessary?

```
var s1:Square = new Square();
trace(s1); // [object Square]
this.addChild(s1);

s1.name = 'Square1';
trace(this.getChildByName("Square1")); // [object Square]
```

The difference is that `getChildByName` returns `null` if your object hasn't been added to the Display List by `addChild` method.

But if you MUST ABSOLUTLY call instances of DisplayObjects by a method, call them by their indice with `getChildAt` method, rather than by their name with `getChildByName` method.

```
trace(this.getChildAt(0)); // [object Square]
```

You shouldn’t use `getChildByName` method which is slower than `getChildAt` method. You can compare the speed of these two methods with the following code:

```
// testing getChildByName
var sta:Number = getTimer();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    getChildByName('Square1');
}
var sto:Number = getTimer();
trace((sto - sta) + ' ms'); // 2299 ms

// testing getChildAt
var sta:Number = getTimer();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    getChildAt(0);
} 
var sto:Number = getTimer();
trace((sto - sta) + ' ms'); // 610 ms
```